# Center two cards in middle of browser window with ReactStrap (Bootstrap4)

Tags: bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I'm using reactstrap (based on Bootstrap4) to create a React app. I am trying to create a side-by-side pair of cards (a login and register set) that, when the browser is small, would go one above the other. I can get them centered horizontally, but not vertically. Seems like the container/row/col does not expand to fill the window. How would one go about centering this?

See https://codesandbox.io/s/71r9x2ynwx for a working example.

Comment: If you apply the css from the alleged duplicate question, it doesn't work. See https://codesandbox.io/s/426277vml9

Comment: Read the other question/answer. All the container(s) (html,body,.container,etc..) of the content you want to center must be full height. https://www.codeply.com/go/WYw4VWxB4F

Comment: Thanks, @ZimSystem, I added the .full-height class and didn't realize I had to add it to both `Container` and `Row`.